# Loop de repetição com saida em pares e sequenciais

Tags: c#

Como posso gerar essa lista em pares sequenciais:

```
Array = Itens.text.Split(","[0]);
int qnt = Array .Length;

    for (int i = 0; i < qnt; i++) 
    {
        TextBox.Text = Array[i].text;
        i++;
        TextBox.Text = Array[i].text;               
    }
```

dessa forma não funciona, mais seu removo o `i++` a saida é assim:

```
TextBox.text = Array[0];
TextBox.text = Array[0]; 

TextBox.text = Array[1];
TextBox.text = Array[1]; 

TextBox.text = Array[2];
TextBox.text = Array[2];
```

queria que a saída fosse assim:

```
TextBox.text = Array[0];
TextBox.text = Array[1]; 

TextBox.text = Array[2];
TextBox.text = Array[3]; 

TextBox.text = Array[4];
TextBox.text = Array[5];
```

e etc, a cada `loop` ele me rotar dessa forma.
se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço!

Comment: O que seriam esses pares? Não entendi muito bem.

Comment: index em pares, Ex `TxtProduto.text = ArrayProdutos[1] e TxtQnt.text = ArrayProdutos[2];` depois `TxtProduto.text = ArrayProdutos[3] e TxtQnt.text = ArrayProdutos[4];` e assim por diante

Comment: Você tem um `array` que o nome do produto está no índice ímpar, e a quantidade no índice par, e você quer preencher caixas de texto com esses valores, mas pra fazer o que exatamente?

Comment: para mostrar os valor do respectivo index, vai gerar uma lista de text box assim: 
Produto 
Quantidade,
Produto 
Quantidade etc.

Comment: Isto não gera uma lista de `TextBox`. Isto faz seus `TextBox` que já existem serem preenchidos várias vezes. Você vai criar estes `TextBox` onde? Em tela? Em relatório? Sua solução é Web Forms?

Comment: veja se ficou mais claro agora =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Array = Itens.text.Split(","[0]);
int qnt = Array .Length;

    for (int i = 1; i < qnt; i += 2)
    {
        TextBox.Text = Array[i-1].text;
        TextBox.Text = Array[i].text;               
    }
```

Comment: não deu cara, da `IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range.`

Comment: tente como meti agora

Comment: é eu pensei nisso também mas sem sucesso, ele da erro logo no Array[i-1]

Comment: aparece o mesmo erro?

Comment: Tente com o While que meti

Comment: fiz um debug e agora esta trazendo os itens invertido do array e depois cai no Exception, a ordem eu arrumei com `i = -1` inves de `0`

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26446/discussion-between-hardcorder-and-hebert-de-lima).

Comment: Muito obrigado! funcionou